# How to highlight_string content from a form within tags pre using php

Tags: php, regex, highlight

I have content that is posted from a WYSIWYG form with ajax where codes are placed between tags

```
stuf before content <pre class="brush: php; light: true; collapse: true; fontsize: 500; first-line: 1; ">
    <?php  echo "Jesus is the way the truth and the life and Jesus is Lord and He is God"; ?>  </pre> stuf after content  <pre class="brush: php; light: true; collapse: true; fontsize: 500; first-line: 1; ">
    <?php $jesusis='Lord';  echo "Another content code"; ?>  </pre>
```

Once the content is posted, before displaying what has been posted, on the backend I want to use the php function highlight_string to highlight every thing between the tags `<pre>` whether they are classes added to the tags pre like in the example above or not.

Once the content is posted, the WYSIWYG editor turns the content to **htmlentities** so the content becomes

```
<p> stuf before content <br /> &nbsp; </p> <pre><code><span style="color: #000000"> <br />&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&amp;lt;?php&nbsp;echo&nbsp;"Jesus&nbsp;is&nbsp;the&nbsp;way&nbsp;the&nbsp;truth&nbsp;and&nbsp;the&nbsp;life&nbsp;and&nbsp;Jesus&nbsp;is&nbsp;Lord&nbsp;and&nbsp;He&nbsp;is&nbsp;God";&nbsp;?&amp;gt; <br /></span> </code></pre> <p> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; <br /> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; stuf after content &nbsp; <br /> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp; </p> <pre><code><span style="color: #000000"> <br />&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&amp;lt;?php&nbsp;$jesusis="Lord";&nbsp;echo&nbsp;"Another&nbsp;content&nbsp;code";&nbsp;?&amp;gt; <br /></span> </code></pre> <p> <br /> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; </p>
```

So basically on the back end I want to replace `<pre>...content ...</pre>` with `<pre>highlight_string ('content')</pre>`.

In order to achieve that I first of all tried to retrieve every match between `<pre>`

```
preg_match('~<pre.*?>(.*?)</pre>~i', $content, $matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE);

//Count number of matches
$compter_matches = count($matches); 

//if we have at least one match 
if($compter_matches>0)
    {

    ###############################
        for($i=0; $i<$compter_matches; $i++)
        {
            $a_remplacer = $matches[$i];
            $replacement = '<pre>'.highlight_string($a_remplacer, true).'</pre>';

$note = preg_replace('~<pre.*?>(.*?)</pre>~i', $replacement, $content);



        }
    ##########################################  
    }
```

But when i do that i get:

> int(2) Notice: Array to string conversion.

**How to highlight_string content from a form within tags `<pre>` and `</pre>` using php ?**

Comment: There were so many issues with your code, I surrendered :) 1.) your regex is not matching anything because of missing `s` flag 2.) If you use `PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE` you get a multidimensional array. 3.) There is no `for` loop needed for `preg_match` output. You get 2 matches at most. You want `$matches[1][0]` (captured inside the parentheses) if using the offset param. Else it would be `$matches[1]`... Have you ever used `var_dump()` ? It's very useful. [Played with your code here](https://shorturl.at/dflTY).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all your `(.*?)` will not match anything that spans across lines because `.` does not match the newline character unless you specify the `s` flag.

Try:

```
<?php

$content = '<p>
    stuf before content
    <br />
    &nbsp;
</p>
<pre class="brush: applescript; fontsize: 100; first-line: 1; ">
    &lt;?php echo "Jesus is the way the truth and the life and Jesus is Lord and He is God"; ?&gt;
</pre>
<p>
    &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <br />
    &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; stuf after content &nbsp;
    <br />
    &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;
</p>
<pre class="brush: applescript; fontsize: 100; first-line: 1; ">
    &lt;?php $jesusis="Lord"; echo "Another content code"; ?&gt;
</pre>
<p>
    <br />
    &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
</p>';

$text = preg_replace_callback(
    '~<pre.*?>(.*?)</pre>~is',
    function($matches) {
        return('<pre>'.highlight_string(html_entity_decode($matches[1]), true).'</pre>');
    },
    $content
    );
echo $text;
```

[See Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/a78a1b840582ca8ce7f6795d2d1eba67f9c48efe)

Comment: This is very close to the answer only that with the WYSIWYG the content is changed to ```htmlentities```. So if you could show me how to deal with it with the change content and display the code I will mark this as answer. Here is an online test of the content when it is posted and your code.
http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/cb0d93740f181bd30eea076c8874844bbc071a2f

Comment: I found the solution based on your answer. I am going to mark this as the answer but please edit your answer and add the following line to it

```$my_matches = html_entity_decode($matches[1]);
        return('<pre>'.highlight_string($my_matches, true).'</pre>');```
Here is a live demo
http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/fe98b46e81aca5cf4c71c99c5e0b645ce09c6b22

Comment: @JohnMax But in your problematic example, your content was not `<?php echo etc.` but rather `&lt;?php echo etc.` and that is why you were having the problem. Check your code's `$content` variable again to see what I mean. You shouldn't need `html_entity_decode` unless you are starting out with encoded input, which was *not* the case in your original question. So which is it? Perhaps you need to edit your question.

Comment: I have edited the question and explained that since i mentioned it is a WYSIWYG as soon as the content is posted it is automatically converted into htmlentities

Answer (score 0):

Hmm,
What about that:

```
<?php
$content = '<pre>sadfasdfsadf</pre>';

$matches = array();

preg_match('~<pre.*?>(.*?)</pre>~i', $content, $matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE);

//Count number of matches
$compter_matches = count($matches); 

//if we have at least one match 
if($compter_matches>0)
{
    for($i = 0; $i < $compter_matches; $i += 2) {
        $a_remplacer = $matches[$i][0];
        $replacement = '<pre>'.highlight_string($a_remplacer[$i+1][0], true).'</pre>';
        $note = str_replace($a_remplacer[$i], $replacement, $content);
    }

    echo $note;
}
```

[online test](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/5192b34cb7ae269e9afb67eeb3cfddeaf11e3e8c)

Comment: Please check an online test at the same place with another input 
http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/a0d86716f654619594d5bf961b59e56caf9e9fd4
It does not highlight the text

Comment: If you read my answer, you will see that this simple test case does not span multiple lines for which you need the `s` flag as in `'~<pre.*?>(.*?)</pre>~is'`.

Comment: Here is an example with your answer with the content after it is posted through the wysiwyg and what it gets 
http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/0beb2cb9c41586be3a5da0ebb899b50ff20af361